# SWIG C# Passing binary data with directors="1"

Tags: c#, swig

I see a java example about how to pass binary data in director callback from C++ to java , https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/90cdbee6a69d13b39d734083b9f91069533b0d7b/Examples/test-suite/director_binary_string.i , I'd like to do the same thing on C# with the same swig directive,

```
%apply (char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) { (char *dataBufferAA, int sizeAA) };
```

but it does not take effect, and shows

```
Warning 453: Can't apply (char const *STRING,size_t LENGTH). No typemaps are defined
```

Basically my code's structure is like below, I'd expect a callback function like `void run(byte[] aData)` can be invoked in C#.

```
%module(directors="1") director_binary_string;

%feature("director") Callback;

%apply (char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) { (char* aData, size_t aLen) };


%inline %{
#include <stdlib.h>


class Callback {
public:
  virtual ~Callback() {}
  virtual void run(char* aData, size_t aLen) {}
};

%}
```

And I tries a typemap like below, but it does not work as expected.

```
%typemap(imtype)   (const char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) "byte[]"
%typemap(cstype)  (const char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) "byte[]"

%typemap(directorin, excode=SWIGEXCODE) (const char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) %{
    {
        $input = new byte[(int)$2];
        IntPtr data = $imcall;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data, $input, 0, (int)$2); 
    }
%}
```

Anyone can show how to write a proper typemap or any other better solution.

Comment: No typemaps defined. You need to define your typemaps before calling `apply`. Typemap definition must appear before `apply`.

Comment: Thanks, I know that, because swig 4.0.2 does not support the passing binary data feature for C# at all, but it is done for java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got an alternative solution. Instead of passing binary data to C# side from C++， within the callback, the caller from C# proactively retrieves binary data. For example

**Swig Interface**

```
%module(directors="1") director_binary_string;

%feature("director") Callback;
%include "arrays_csharp.i"


%inline %{
#include <stdlib.h>

class CallbackData 
{
public:
    %apply unsigned char INOUT[] { unsigned char* aBlockData}
    bool GetBlockData(unsigned char* aBlockData);
    size_t GetSize();
};

class Callback {
public:
  virtual ~Callback() {}
  virtual void run(CallbackData aCB) {}
};
```

**C#**

```
class csharp_callback : Callback
{
    public override void run(CallbackData aCB)
    {
       byte[] aData = new byte[aCB.GetSize()];
       aCB.GetBlockData(aData);
       //aData is the expected binary data.
    }
}
```